# Where do I insert progress bar code in python?

Tags: python, function, progress

I'm having difficulty in getting a progress bar working in python 2.7. I have this code that I really like:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(101):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

from a source that was posted here earlier. However, my difficulty is in getting the code to calculate the progress of a function that I want to run. For example:

```
def example(n):
     print n ** 10
```

My question is, how can i get the progress bar to, well, progress, for this function?

Comment: If your function is only one line long, it doesn't make much sense to me to have a progress indicator. Before the first line, it's 0% done. After the first line, it's 100% done.

Comment: Right. I'm just using this as a model for a much longer version that could take hours to compute. I was using this for simplicity's sake.

Comment: The most straightforward approach is to just sprinkle those `sys.stdout` lines throughout your code, in positions that you think are approximately evenly distributed time-wise. There's no generic algorithm that can determine how close a function is to completion, since that would require solving the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Hmm, ok. I've placed it in and I do get a progress. Thanks for the suggestion! How do progress bars work in programs then if there's this halting problem?

Comment: For programs that aren't able to determine ahead of time how long they'll take, they just guess. Often [very badly](https://xkcd.com/612/). I expect there's a lot of complicated math you can do to make reasonably accurate guesses, but that's pretty far outside my area of expertise.

Comment: They don't. It's impossible unless you've computed it before and know when it will end.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you know how much work needs to be done, but not how much will it take. For example, you have a list of images you need to process, so you know the total amount of work. But you don't know how much time will take to process each image, because each image is different in size for example. So, you show the progress bar in terms of the total amount of work and not the percent of time done.

In particular, about the progress bar, you can do something like this.

```
import time
import sys

def progress(percent):
    floor = int(percent)
    sys.stdout.write('\r' * (floor + 9))
    sys.stdout.write('[')
    sys.stdout.write('=' * floor)
    sys.stdout.write('] {:02.2f}%'.format(percent))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> for i in range(101):
...     time.sleep(0.1)
...     progress(float(i))
... else:
...     print('')
... 
[==========================] 26.00%
```

[EDIT]

Following the example of the image processing, you can write something like:

```
>>> images = range(300)
>>> 
>>> def process_image(img):
...     # Heavy processing here
...     # Do whatever you need to do here for each input
...     time.sleep(0.1)
... 
>>> for i, img in enumerate(images, 1):
...     process_image(img)
...     percent = (i / float(len(images))) * 100
...     progress(percent)
... 
[====================] 20.00%
```

Comment: Well, kinda. That's an awesome progress bar. But it's keeping the time of the function time.sleep(0.1), not the progress of a general function. For example, if you were to write any function, the progress bar should keep track of how far along (in percentage) this is.

Comment: Again, time? If you expect to know how much time will it take you're out of luck. If you expect to show the amount of work done then just adapt it.

Comment: How would I adapt it?